# Datatables Checkbox Unserialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, datatables

im currently using dataTables plugin to display and manage some content in an application.

Every row in the table is being marked with an `<input type="checkbox" />`

Then in JS i do

```
var dataString = $('input[type=checkbox]', oTable.fnGetNodes()).serialize();
```

In order to get a string with all of the data and pass it via Ajax to server side, that's to delete the elements, they get deleted fine and the parent rows get removed from the DOM using `.remove()` , so i don't have to refresh the page after delete

Let's suppose i just deleted the item with id **1**, then i check item with id **2** On that second approach the item with id **1** it's still getting serialized and sent to the server side, which causes a notice since the element does not exists any longer on the DB.

How can i work it out? i tried `fnDraw()` but it is not working.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

At the end i managed to solve it by using

```
$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Right after the success on the ajax function.